# My code opens all accordions for the script

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, accordion, bootstrap-accordion

For this code, I mean to open one accordion and close the remaining ones, but when I click on anything for the first time, it is opening all the accordions. Subsequent times it's opening only the correct one.

```
function cloz(a) {
  if (a == 1) {
    $("#myaccordion1").collapse('show');
    $("#myaccordion2").collapse('hide');
    $("#myaccordion3").collapse('hide');
    $("#myaccordion4").collapse('hide');
    $("#myaccordion5").collapse('hide');
    $("#myaccordion6").collapse('hide');
  }
  if (a == 2) {
    $("#myaccordion1").collapse('hide');
    $("#myaccordion2").collapse('show');
    $("#myaccordion3").collapse('hide');
    $("#myaccordion4").collapse('hide');
    $("#myaccordion5").collapse('hide');
    $("#myaccordion6").collapse('hide');
  }
  if (a == 3) {
    $("#myaccordion1").collapse('hide');
    $("#myaccordion2").collapse('hide');
    $("#myaccordion3").collapse('show');
    $("#myaccordion4").collapse('hide');
    $("#myaccordion5").collapse('hide');
    $("#myaccordion6").collapse('hide');
  }
```

Comment: If i click on cloz(1) its showing 1, 2 and 3 for the first time

Comment: You should really use a single class to select all those elements and then find the one you want by it index. That way you can do all of the above code in one line.

Comment: Please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

I think you can simplify your code a bit. First thing, if you can, use a class for all your accordions. Then you can do something like this:

```
function cloz(a) {
    $('.accordion').collapse('hide');
    $('.accordion').eq(a).collapse('show');
}
```

So you first close all accordions, and then open the one you want. The .eq(n) function select the n element of a list of elements.

Comment: Nice answer, although it could be a single line to save accessing the DOM twice - `$('.accordion').collapse('hide').eq(a).collapse('show');`